# Two different applications (Heroku and EC2) on the one domain name

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, mod-rewrite, heroku

Is it possible to point my Heroku application to https://myawesomeapp.com and my EC2 wordpress server pointing to http://myawesomeapp.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible but its not good practice to point two app to same domain name. Some user will get ur heroku app and some users will get Wordpress sitedepends upon the DNS resolution from the network.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible, yes - I wouldnt say it's bad practise, or that users will get different things depending on DNS either.

IIS will certainly let you run different websites on different ports - so simply run one on HTTP, and the other on HTTPS.

I don't know what web server you're using though.

Comment: We can't edit the Heroku web server and the EC2 server would be running apache